# align code statement (type,variable,equal sign,etc) for a group of lines in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, tabs

Does Visual Studio has tab-customization like in the Microsoft Words?
It is also useful for some dirty refactoring (e.g. [block-editing](http://visualstudiotipsandtricks.com/blog/2013/04/20/select-and-edit-vertical-blocks/)).

With this feature, I don't have to `space space space` / `tab tab tab` manually anymore to make it pretty like :-

[image]

In Microsoft Words, I can assign selected lines to have customized positions of tab :-

[image]

It works like this (`->` are the tab characters):-

[image]

### Edit

Code alignment extension recommend by a solution from VTT doesn't work for this code :-

```
std::vector<int> cat =std::vector<int>() ;
float zombie=5;
```

I expect it to be formatted like :-

```
std::vector<int> cat    = std::vector<int>() ;
float            zombie = 5;
```

But this is the result (at best):-

```
std::vector<int>     cat =std::vector<int>() ;
float zombie             =5;
```

### Edit2

Here is an example more similar to the real case:-

```
MyArray<ManagerAAC   >   packAAC =create  (userData);
MyArray<ManagerANC  >   packANC =createANC  ( userData);
MyArray<ManagerAIC  >   packAIC =createAIC  (userData );
MyArray< ManagerNDX<1>>   packNDX1=generate<1>(userData);
MyArray<ManagerNDX<2>>    packNDX2=generate<2>(userData);
MyArray<ManagerNDX<3>>    packNDX3=generate<3>  (userData);
MyArray<ManagerSSK >      packSSK =createSSK     (userData);
```

I would be nice if it is formatted to be :-

```
MyArray<ManagerAAC   >    packAAC =create     (userData);
MyArray<ManagerANC   >    packANC =createANC  (userData);
MyArray<ManagerAIC   >    packAIC =createAIC  (userData);
MyArray<ManagerNDX<1>>    packNDX1=generate<1>(userData);
MyArray<ManagerNDX<2>>    packNDX2=generate<2>(userData);
MyArray<ManagerNDX<3>>    packNDX3=generate<3>(userData);
MyArray<ManagerSSK   >    packSSK =createSSK  (userData);
```

It also enables block-editing e.g. :-

[image]

I want to use it in just a few files (<1% of amount of `.h`/`.cpp`).

Comment: `I expect it to be formatted like` ... - I would definitely reject that kind of formatting. How about getting used to not making your code "beautiful" like a Christmas tree?

Comment: this is not nice at all: `MyArray<ManagerAAC   >    packAAC =create         (userData);` bunch of random spaces all over the place. It's not even obviously clear anymore that there is a function call there.

Comment: aligning these operators does not scale and can cause multiple line edits when you introduce a new symbol that pushes all the equality operators to the right, not good value in maintenance just for the sake of looking pretty. Your code does not need to be tabular to be readable. There is a reason whey the mainline coding conventions do not endorse operator alignments across multiple lines.

Comment: A bit of tangential information: the customizable tab positions in Word and other publishing software are called "Tab Stops".  That's an industry standard term so may help anyone doing related internet searches.

Answer (score 9):

You can install [Code alignment](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cpmcgrath.Codealignment) extension. It does not work like Word, but it does format your code without much typing.

Comment: While the `=`-mode work, the space-mode doesn't work if there is noise e.g. `<>`. (I edited the question.)  Is it a known bug?

Comment: You can use the "Align by..." together `> ` (angle + space)... then align by equal... previously you should apply a formatter to reduce extra spaces and let the aligner to introduce them back in the right place

Comment: @cbuchart I can't make it work in some cases.  Here is a mcve :  https://pastebin.com/rmd59NSW ...  I can't align `,` for this code, even when use `align by ...` and fill the textbox with `,`.  Do you happen to know how to?

Comment: Code Alignment will align respect the first occurrence of the string (`,` in your case), not all of them. This is, for me, the main drawback of this tool. On the other hand, as I mentioned before, you should preprocess your code with a formatter in order to clean up unwanted spaces and similars; this helps a lot in code alignment.

Answer (score 8):

Format it like this:

```
std::vector<int> cat = std::vector<int>();
float zombie = 5;
```

and do not waste time on something that doesn't matter.

Comment: I won't downvote, but sorry, it is matter for me in real world.  I want to be able to edit as code block easily. (using alt+mouse drag)  Do you happen to know alternatives?

Comment: edit manually. Do block edits (column mode edit) in VS to move blocks faster. hold `Alt`+`Shift` and press a few times down and then press `space` to type spaces in multiple lines simultaneously.

Comment: @javaLover it's similar to alt+mouse drag, but can be done with keyboard alone. Also, make sure you use spaces for this kind of formatting, as other editors and tools might make your code look totally weird.

Comment: VS and many other common extensions (like visual assist) will do some code alignment, but not for cases like this one. IMO it doesn't make sense to do it most of the time. In large similar blocks of code, maybe, but for the rest of unrelated variables it doesn't even make sense to make them look aligned.

Comment: I agree that most of the time, it doesn't make sense.   However, I still want to ease my workflow for some rare cases.

Answer (score 2):

Visual studio does have built in automatic formatting ( Edit -> Advanced ) which can be customised in the options menu ( Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> [language] -> Formatting)

There you can customise how the formatting behaves, although it may not be precise enough to achieve exactly what you want it should be able to get pretty close.

[image: example options screen]

Answer (score -3):

Do not do that kind of formatting.  Each line of code should be readable on its own.  As another comment said, if you take any one of those lines and isolate it, it is terribly ugly and unreadable.

You are asking us to help your code look worse.

Comment: I partially disagree: it's true that if you isolate one of those line of code then any previous alignment is just noise, but the same is valid for indentation. On the other hand, discrete and smart alignment may make code actually more readable since give coherence to the block, makes clear that they are all related and it is easier to detect typos (not-compilation errors), for example.

Comment: I agree, sometimes it make sense to do some minor manual reformatting, but if that makes individual lines look weird like `MyArray<ManagerAAC   >    packAAC =create     (userData);` mentioned by the OP  I would not accept that